# Child component emit to parent and parent update all children components

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

I'm trying to create a list with expandable items using vue js 2. The idea is that when I click on an item I want it to expand(show it's content) if it's not already expanded and close all the other expanded elements. I have created two components `expandable-panel` and `expandable-item`. I can have multiple types of contents inside so I want to use slots.

The code I have:

`ExpandablePanel` component:

```
<template>
    <div class="expandable-panel" @expanded="doStuff">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/babel">
    export default {
        methods: {
            doStuff: function() {
                alert('expanded');
            }
        }
     }
</script>
```

The `ExpandableItem` component:

```
<template>
    <div class="expandable-item" @click="toggleExpand">
        <div class="expandable-item-header">
            {{ title }}
        </div>
        <div class="expandable-item-body" v-if="expanded">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script type="text/babel">
    export default {
        props: {
            title: String
            // expanded: {
            //     type: Boolean,
            //     default: true
            // }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                expanded: true
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggleExpand: function() {
                this.expanded = !this.expanded;
                this.$emit('expand');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And my HTML file

```
<expandable-panel>
    <expandable-item title='title 1'>Lorem ipsum...</expandable-item>
    <expandable-item title='title 2'>Lorem ipsum...</expandable-item>
    <expandable-item title='title 3'>Lorem ipsum...</expandable-item>
</expandable-panel>
```

My app and components are registered like this:

```
Vue.component('expandable-panel',    require('./components/global/ExpandablePanel.vue'));
Vue.component('expandable-item', require('./components/global/ExpandableItem.vue'));
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Problems:
The `$emit` part doesn't seem to reach to the `@expanded="doStuff"` inside the parent component.
Even if it reaches there how do I properly toggle the `expanded` values? Can I use props for this?

Right now, it toggles each elements but I can't update the others.
Thank you

Comment: Yes, You can control it via props or also explore some state management like [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have here the strict relationship between parent and child, so you can emit event via $parent object.

First, on parent object creation, listen for your event with `this.$on`:

```
Vue.component('parent', {
  template: `<div><slot></slot></div>`,
  created: function() {
    this.$on('event', function(message) {
        alert(message);
    })
  }
});
```

Then inside your child component emit this event with `$parent.$emit`

```
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<button @click="$parent.$emit('event', 'From child')">I'm slot</button>`
});
```

Here is working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rdjjpc7a/1754/

Answer (score 0):

In the `ExpandablePanel` component: you should only have `@expand` as that is what you are emitting from the child:

```
<template>
    <div class="expandable-panel" @expand="doStuff">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have one question. Where should I define the `doStuff` method if it should not be inside `ExpandablePanel`?

Comment: @NightFall It depends on how you want to structure your app, Does parent needs to be aware of whether child is expanded or not?